# Is there a way to set defaultValues in a child component using react hook form with useFieldArray hook - not using the useForm hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

## Problem

I want to implement key/value pairs of input fields in a form that can be added by a user.

- See [animated gif on dynamic fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv55J.gif).

In addition, I want to display saved data when the user has submitted the form and the page is displayed again.

- See [animated gif on displaying saved dynamic fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYQ5M.gif).

### Preconditions

- I'm using `react-hook-form V7` (RHF) and its `useFieldArray` hook.
- As I use Material-UI I have to use `controlled components`.

### Working solution

In a simplified app, I have a parent component using the `useForm` hook and two child components, one for the purpose of demonstration holding normal form fields and an `<ArrayFields />` component holding the array fields.

Yesterday I learned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70853991/4169247) that one way to do it is to set the `defaultValues` object in the parent's useForm hook like this:

```
const methods = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      email: "john.smith@example.com",
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Smith",
      systemRole: "Admin",
      envRoles: [                             // <-- saved dynamic fields
        { envName: "foo1", envRole: "bar1" },
        { envName: "foo2", envRole: "bar2" }
      ]
    }
  });
```

Here you can see a [codesandbox of this working solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-defaultvalues-forked-znch0?file=/src/index.js).

## Question

Nonetheless, I am wondering if it isn't possible to set the `defaultValues` in the `<ArrayFields />` child component?

### useFormContext approach

For example like this using the `useFormContext` hook:

```
// 
const ArrayFields = ({ fieldset }) => {
  const { control, getValues } = useFormContext({
    defaultValues: {
      envRoles: [
        { envName: "foo1", envRole: "bar1" },
        { envName: "foo2", envRole: "bar2" }
      ]
    }
  });
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "envRoles"
  });

  ...
}
```

- But this is not displaying the saved fields at all
- See here [a codesandbox version of the useFormContext approach](https://codesandbox.io/s/rhf-usefieldarray-defaultvalues-via-useformcontext-ktz87?file=/src/ArrayFields.js:105-437)

### Props approach

Next, I tried to pass the fields (alias `envRoles`) as props and set the `defaultValues` to the Controller directly

```
// index.js:30
<ArrayFields
  fieldset={[
    { envName: "foo1", envRole: "bar1" },
    { envName: "foo2", envRole: "bar2" }
  ]}
/>

// ArrayFields.js:35
<Controller
  render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />}
  defaultValue={item.envName}                   {/* <-- defaultValue on Controller */}
  name={`envRoles[${index}].envName`}
  control={control}
/>
```

- This displays the `defaultValues`
- but does not work when clicking on the add or delete button
- See [this codesandbox of the props approach](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-defaultvalues-via-props-cb1bi?file=/src/ArrayFields.js:493-696)

### Question again

So is it really true that RHF does not allow handling all things that matter to the component inside this component?

Thanks in advance for your hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

[In the documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray) of `useFieldArray` you'll find the `replace` method.

```
replace (obj: object[]) => void     Replace the entire field array values.
```

So using a `useEffect` hook it's finally easy.

```
useEffect(() => {
  replace(fieldset);
}, [fieldset, replace]);
```

In [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-defaultvalues-via-props-and-replace-7s8lp) you will find the example that finally works with setting the defaultValues in the child component.

Comment: Is there a way to this for Select dropdown and Radio components ?. Specifically passing default values to child Radio and Select components and how to handle onChange events at the parent component.